# Как передать значение из адресной строки в js

Tags: javascript

[image]

Как передать в js значение id?

```
var id = [значение из адресной строки]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать класс [`Url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
console.log(url.searchParams.get("id"));
```

Либо еще проще:

```
console.log(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("id"));
```